# Accessing Another .edmx file in Controler/View

Tags: model-view-controller

Hi i have two connection strings both connecting to database

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="EISystemEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.EISystemModel.csdl|res://*/Models.EISystemModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.EISystemModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=***-DEV-APP01;initial catalog=EISystem;persist security info=True;user id=****;password=*****;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
<add name="UserAccountsDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.DB.UserAccountsModel.csdl|res://*/Models.DB.UserAccountsModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.DB.UserAccountsModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=***-DEV-APP01;initial catalog=EISystem;user id=*****;password=*****;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I have a MultipleViewModel setup

```
namespace EISystem.Models
 public class MultipleModelViewModel
{



    public company CompanyEntities { get; set; }
    public Description Descriptions { get; set; }
    public Company_Contact ContactEntities { get; set; }
    public ComType TypeEntities { get; set; }
    public country CountryEntities { get; set; }
    public Year_Established EstablishedEntities { get; set; }
    public Employee employeeEntities { get; set; }
    public Region RegionEntities { get; set; }
    public Region ExportRegionEntities { get; set; }
    public Register_Title TitleEntities { get; set; }
    public SYSUser UserEntities { get; set; }

}
```

NB: SYSUser is part of the 2nd connection string i.e UserAccountsDBEntities

How can access a field of  2nd connection string(UserAccountsDBEntities) in VIEW
like `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ContactEntities.ContactID)`

"0" is Currently displayed `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to rather make one connectionString. and implimant MultipleModelView class

```
 public class MultipleModelViewModel
{
    public MultipleModelViewModel()
   {
      TitleEntities = new Register_Title();
      ContactEntities = new Company_Contact();
      CompanyEntities = new company();
       //Descriptions = new Description();
      CountryEntities = new country();
      EstablishedEntities = new Year_Established();
      UserEntities = new SYSUser();
      UserRoleEntities = new SYSUserRole();
      UserProfileEntities = new SYSUserProfile();
   }


    public company CompanyEntities { get; set; }
    public Description Descriptions { get; set; }
    public Company_Contact ContactEntities { get; set; }
    public ComType TypeEntities { get; set; }
    public country CountryEntities { get; set; }
    public Year_Established EstablishedEntities { get; set; }
    public Employee employeeEntities { get; set; }
    public Region RegionEntities { get; set; }
    public Region ExportRegionEntities { get; set; }
    public Register_Title TitleEntities { get; set; }
    public SYSUser UserEntities { get; set; }
    public SYSUserRole UserRoleEntities { get; set; }
    public SYSUserProfile UserProfileEntities { get; set; }

}
```